# how to get rid of all trailing question marks and exclamation points in a string - ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How can I get rid of the trailing question marks and exclamation points in this string:

```
 str = "Hello!!!!! World???"
```

so that the final result is:

```
str = "Hello! World?"
```

I only want the first `"?"` and `"!"` in the string.

Comment: You can get rid of them by writing code that removes them. What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a precise specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? For example, what should the result be for `'Hello?!? World?!?'`? Or for `'Hello??World??'`?

Comment: I only want to keep the very first "?" and "!" that appear in the string

Comment: @JörgWMittag assumed you have given an example of how you would like certain strings to be modified. (After all, if you are only concerned with that one specific string you could just write `str = "Hello! World!"`--there would be nothing to calculate.) Presumably, your question concerns a class (not `Class`) of strings with certain properties. You need to state the question in a precise and complete way in words, with your example merely illustrative. This is the problem (which occurs all the time on SO) of trying to state a question in the context of a specific example.

Comment: So, the result output for `'Hello?! Cruel!! World!!'` should be `'Hello?! Cruel World'`. And the output for `'Hello!?!?'` should be `'Hello!?'`. Then, why did you accept an answer where the output is `'Hello?'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably tackle it with a simple regular expression:

```
while (line = DATA.gets)
  puts line.chomp.gsub(/([\?\!])+/, '\1')
end

__END__
Hello!! World??
Hello!?!?
Hello!!!!!!
```

Which yields:

```
Hello! World?
Hello?
Hello!
```

Just using `DATA` here for convenience, but this will work on any strings you might have.

Comment: Does the `!` in the regex have to be escaped?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Maybe not, but I tend to do that sort of thing out of an abundance of caution.

Answer (score 5):

```
"Hello!!!!! World????".squeeze('!?')
  #=> "Hello! World?"
```

See [String#squeeze](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-squeeze). Use `squeeze!` to modify the string in place.

Comment: Now that's a slick solution.